# 'The default Firebase app has not yet been configured' error

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I'm getting this error in my iOS app with Firebase integrated:

```
<Error> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add [FIRApp configure] to your application initialization
```

However I've already added `[FIRApp configure]` in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [FIRApp configure];
 }
```

How do I fix this? I'm also using Firebase Authentication, Database, and Messaging all with Pods.

Comment: did you download google-Plist from firebase console ?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Answer (score -1):

Something might be missing in your steps. Try this way:

1. Visit https://console.firebase.google.com/ and login
2. Click on "Add Project" (if you have not created one already)
3. Enter project name, enable/disable analytics (as per your project requirement) etc and create a project. In few seconds to minutes, it will create a project for you.
4. It takes you to home page with projects listing.
5. Click on the project you created. It shows "Add an App" and
   select "iOS"
6. Provide all the details they asked for, like app
   name, nick name, App Store id etc.
7. It generates a plist file that you can download and add it to your project.

Then your code works perfect.